# Jquery caption style item

Tags: jquery, css

I like to have the title tag caption over a float list of image...
i have manage to make some jquery to get and do the cation 
but the placement or the css dont work...

maybe my "base" is wrong.... HELP

this is the page: http://pfibco.ca/04-accessoires-fra.php?lang=fra

and this is the inspiration [link](http://homegel.co.za/imagecaption/)

Comment: What mark up are you working with? Can you post a demo of what you've got so far, and maybe a screen shot of what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the proper answer [here](http://www.jqueryfun.com/2010/06/20/make-nice-captions-using-image-alternative-tag/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Make Nice Captions Using Image Alternative Tag</title>
  <style>
    /* Style wrapping elements */
    .caption {position: relative; display: block;}
    .caption div {position: absolute; padding: 5px; bottom: 0; text-align: center; line-height: 150%; color: #ffffff; background: #000000;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Make Nice Captions Using Image Alternative Tag</h1>
  <img src="path to the image goes here" alt="Here goes the alternative text which pops out on hover" />
</body>

</html>
```

and or the jquery part :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Wrap up images
  $('img').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="caption"></div>').after('<div>' + $(this).attr('alt') + '</div>');
    $('.caption').width($(this).width()).children('div').each(function() {
      $(this).css({width: $(this).siblings('img').width(), opacity: 1, display: 'block'});
    });
  });
});
</script>
```